# Zend REMOTE DEBUGGING help!

Tags: php, debugging, zend-studio, zend-debugger

i have spent the last 2 days trying to get remote debugging working from my windows machine at home to my remote centOS server running WHM/Cpanel..

I am coming from a VS background and can't believe it can be this difficult. Feeling pretty useless at this point!

Ok boo hoo for me. Here is my setup:

- Firewall on local windows machine is turned OFF
- Zend remote debugger installed and confirmed through phpinfo.php
- dummy.php installed on webroot of project
- zend_debugger.allow_hosts=24.150.xxx.xx,192.168.1.118,127.0.0.1

the first ip is my router IP, then my machine ip..I keep getting the following error:

Failed to connect to host '192.168.1.118'. Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to open debug sessions - please configure zend_debugger.allow_hosts in the ini file.

ANY help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Is your phpinfo() showing the allowed hosts config correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using NAT on your local network which means that you need to either explicitly pass connections on port 10120 (you will need to verify this) to your local deve box or use tunneling.  I would recommend tunneling (http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=109) since it will probably be easier.